# Android Navigation component - can't use Extras and Safe Args

Tags: java, android, android-safe-args

I'm using the Android Navigation component with SafeArgs, and I want to add a shared element transition to an action. According to [the documentation,](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(androidx.navigation.NavDirections,androidx.navigation.Navigator.Extras)) I should be able to simply add an Extras object as a parameter to `navigate()`, so I try that:

```
FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                .addSharedElement(view, "group_transition")
                .build();
NavDirections action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToViewFragment(title);
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action, extras);
```

but Android Studio gives an error, and says it can't resolve the method. I try to use

`.navigate(int resId, Bundle args, NavOptions navOptions, Navigator.Extras navigatorExtras)`

which narrows the problem down to the `Navigator.Extras`. Android Studios puts an error under that argument, telling me:

> Required Type: androidx.navigation.Navigator.Extras,
> Provided Type: androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.Extras"

Which I can't figure out. `Navigator.Extras` is an interface, which `FragmentNavigator.Extras` [implements](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/FragmentNavigator.Extras). What can I do about this, other than giving up on the transition I want?

Comment: I think this is a bug in Android Studio. The project still builds and app runs fine with this error.

Comment: After two months, still no one has a solution?

Comment: This Android Studio bug is also present in Android Studio Chipmunk **without** SafeArgs plugin. As @Amit Jayant says, the project still builds OK and transitions behave as expected.